# How can I use ScriptManager more than one function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

```
if (mod != 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Funcm()", true);
}

if (ven != 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Funcv()", true);
}

if (loc != 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Funcl()", true);

}

if (st != 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Funcst()", true);
}
```

Only the first "if" works and hides the item but others are not working, how can I solve this problem?

```
function Funcm() { document.getElementById("ModelMenu").style.display = "none";}
function Funcv() { document.getElementById("VendorMenu").style.display = "none";}
function Funcl() { document.getElementById("LocMenu").style.display = "none";}
function Funcst() { document.getElementById("StatusMenu").style.display = "none";}
```

Comment: The problem I guess is your logic / if statement conditions, i.e. put a breakpoint on the if (mod != 1) and run through your code.

Comment: I tried this, it goes in every "if".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try something more likes this, i.e. only register one script...

```
string myScript = string.Empty;

if (mod != 1)
{
    myScript += "document.getElementById(\"ModelMenu\").style.display = \"none\";";
}

if (ven != 1)
{
    myScript += "document.getElementById(\"VendorMenu\").style.display = \"none\";";
}

if (loc != 1)
{
    myScript += "document.getElementById(\"LocMenu\").style.display = \"none\";";
}

if (st != 1)
{
    myScript += "document.getElementById(\"StatusMenu\").style.display = \"none\";";
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myScript))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myScript", myScript, true);
}
```

or if your functions are predefined and you must use them:

```
string myScript = string.Empty;

if (mod != 1)
{
    myScript += "Funcm();";
}

if (ven != 1)
{
    myScript += "Funcv();";
}

if (loc != 1)
{
    myScript += "Funcl();";
}

if (st != 1)
{
    myScript += "Funcst();";
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myScript))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myScript", myScript, true);
}
```